# How to add .Net Framework to Project setup in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-framework-version

I have made a c# project setup, but i am not able to install it on windows xp, as it prompts me to install framework 4.0, is there any way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you want to integrate a bootstrapper on your setup, so that it automatically install .net 4.0 when the app install itself, or you just want to run the app?

Comment: I just want my app to run

Comment: It will run if you change the .net version of the project to a lower one. Or it will also run if you get a newer operating system. I imagine the former is the easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Download .net 4.0 setup and install on your Operating System...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, install Framework 4! If the Os is stopping you then, short of installing a virtual machine or some other hack I'd suggest updating your OS.

Or change the framework version to 2.0/3.5 in the project.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way around the OS limitation for projects running 4.0/4.5, you have to be on Vista or higher. If the project you're working on doesn't require 4+ then I'd create a 2/3.5 project instead, XP can handle that framework fine.